# JasperReports Server not working on Tomcat6 : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, ubuntu, jasperserver

I've been trying to figure this our all day. I'm trying to get *JasperReports Server* to work on a *Tomcat 6* server.

I keep getting this error `ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter,http-8080-2:101 - Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: could not open relation mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory)`

I have postgresql.jdbc installed in `/usr/share/tomcat6/lib`

My webapp (*JR Server*) is in `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

had to run `killall postgres`

I forgot I had installes postgres before i realized that I needed the .jar.